# Hyperlinks for PDF in the iPhone

Tags: objective-c

How to add/access hyperlinks (both internal and web page) in the PDF in iphone?

Sri

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are asking this from a user or implementation perspective, I assume implementation as this is a programming Q/A site:

The PDF will more than likely be rasterized to an image for the phone, it will be up to the reader to extract the text/links and overlay these over the image to make them clickable.

I have seen this type of thing in flash readers/pagers where these link/hotspots are configured manually, obviously not an option for a generic PDF reader

Answer (score 0):

This is the best that I have found on SO: [Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints). Many links and helpful tips.